# Access issues in synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-synchronization, locks

I have some doubts in synchronization :

1. if i make a call to non-synchronized method from synchronized method
   will non-synchronized method be lock free or not, can other
   method(instance method) still access non-synchronized method ?
2. if i am having class level lock can other thread access synchronized
   instance methods at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

1. A thread entering a `synchronized` instance method obtains a lock on an object (`this`), but it does not lock the whole object. It prevents two threads from entering the synchronized (instance) method(s) at the same time, but other non-synchronized methods can still be executed concurrently by other threads.
2. A class level lock will prevent a thread from entering any of the synchronized class level (static) methods. Synchronized instance method obtain a lock for the current instance (`this`). As these are not the same locks, synchronized instance methods will not be blocked.

A good summary of the topic can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)